# Does group by with having require aggregate function on the select instruction?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, having

Let's say I have a table

> InspectLog​(​userid, attr1, attr2)

I want to know the userid of the users who inspected more than 5 times.

Here's what I have figured out so far:

```
SELECT I.userid
 FROM InspectLog I
 GROUP BY I.userid
 HAVING Count(*) >5;
```

My question is, as I've seen a lot of examples out there when a `having` is used they also call `Count()` in the select instruction like so.

```
SELECT I.userid, Count(*) AS c
 FROM InspectLog I
 GROUP BY I.userid
 HAVING Count(*)>5;
```

Does `having` require to use the aggregate function at the start in the select instruction? Will the output be the same. From what I'm getting the output will differ in having an extra c column in this case. But will the Count() on HAVING  work properly without the first one?

Comment: No, you don't need to select the count(). But why do you ask us, why not try and see what happens?

Comment: If you're interested in the exact number, then you project the count, otherwise not. It's similar to WHERE, you don't have to project the column used in WHERE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, you do not need to add "Count()" in the Select Clause.

It'll only add an extra column in the result.